# How can I check some variable while code is holding on accepting new socket?

Tags: java, sockets, synchronization

In a application that I made, server accepts socket connection from clients and do various work. List of clients is stored in `clients` which has a `LinkedList` type.

I am using while statement with conditional statement based on size of the `clients` queue.

I want to know if there is a way to solve problems described below... so that server will not hang forever.

```
while(clients.size()>0){ //few clients the queue is alive at the moment
    //Suddenly, all clients in the queue shut down at this point in the while loop,
    //Another thread, which checks clients knows that clients are dead
    //so clients.size() becomes 0, but there is no way to check that at this point
    //and server is expecting for connection clients forever

    Socket socket= server.accept();
    socket.close();
}
//printout results
```

**edit**

The clients list is not just existing clients. It is a list of alive clients. This list is gets updated by another thread.

I have while statement above, because I want to do some job after there is no alive clients left. (either finished their job, or just died)

I want to solve this problem without using timeout exception, because clients will response in random time. (again, liveness of clients is checked by another Thread with heartbeat technique)

Comment: Why do you want a solution that does not use timeouts? There's nothing wrong with using a `SocketTimeoutException`. You can catch it inside a loop and handle it appropriately (see my answer for an example). You can also set different timeouts for different sockets if you wish.

Comment: Because..clients must response to the server with the result that they have worked on. This can take 1 second, or 1 minute based on the arguments given to the clients. That is why I am managing clients queue with alive clients. This list is updated by another thread.

Comment: Yes, but you can have a timeout waiting for *the next connection* inside a loop. The timeout does *not* mean that you give up on the next client, it just gives you an opportunity to check if you should still be waiting. Waiting indefinitely is almost always a bad idea. What happens if a client crashes, or there is a power cut before it responds? What if you have network issues? You **need** to be able to handle these cases if you're writing a robust system. Basically, if you *don't* have a timeout then your call to `socket.accept` will wait forever. Is this really what you want?

Comment: I now get your idea. A lot of thanks to you. I thought timeout was removing the ServerSocket and not accepting sockets anymore... I am really sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the timeout on the `ServerSocket` and catch the `SocketTimeoutException`:

```
server.setSoTimeout(1000);
while (clients.size() > 0) {
    try {
        server.accept();
    }
    catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
        // Ignore
    }
}
```

This way you will check the status of the client list every second or so.

Don't forget to synchronize access to `clients` if you have other threads accessing it. Either wrap it using `Collections.synchronizedList` or put appropriate synchronization in the parts of your code that access the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop condition doesn't make any sense to me. Why would you only be interested in accepting new clients when there are existing clients? How does this process ever get started?

But in general setting a timeout on the ServerSocket will let the accept() method throw SocketTimeoutExceptions at those intervals so you can test whatever you need to test.

Comment: It should be `accepting connection among alive clients, while there are existing alive clients`. but not `accepting new clients when there are existing clients`

Comment: @user482594 That statement is a contradiction in terms. Try again.

Comment: User482594: I strongly suspect @EJP understands distributed systems rather well. Setting a timeout is **ideal** for when the server cannot know how long it will take for clients to request a connection to the server. The only alternative is to wait forever.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I've fully understood your question, but assuming a few things the following might work. First assumption is that your Client class has a flag **alive** in it indicating if it is alive or dead.

```
while(clients.size()>0){
    client = clients.remove();
    if (client.isAlive()) {
        Socket socket= server.accept();
        socket.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What if `if(client.isAlive()) {` goes through, and client dies right after that and before getting accepted by server?

Comment: There is typically a TimeoutException configured to handle such a situation. So checkout what Cameron is saying.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a need for synchronisation on clients so that the size of clients is changed at known points.

Answer (score 0):

How about an extra thread to stop the serversocket when all clients are gone? :) Something like

```
new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        if (clients.isEmpty()) {
            try { server.close();} catch (IOException e){...}
        }
    }
}.start();

while(clients.size()>0){ 
    if (!clients.isEmpty()) {
        Socket socket= server.accept();
        socket.close();
    }
}
```